# to break something to be open

Tags: grammar

a) I **broke** the egg **open**.

b) i **broke** the egg **to be open**.

Is the sentence **a)** derived from sentence **b)** but with "to be" omitted?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has been omitted. **[break open](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20open)** is a phrasal verb. Phrasal verbs are made up of a verb and one or two particles, and generally have a different meaning to the verb on its own, for example:

> [break in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-in) - enter a building illegally
> [break up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-up) - when a marriage or relationship ends

Comment: JavaLatte, Thank you!